# Typescript Error in mongoose schemas pre method: Unexpected aliasing of 'this' to local variable

Tags: mongodb, typescript, ionic-framework, mongoose, bcrypt

I'm trying to implement authentication based on MongoDB and NestJS for an Ionic application and getting the following error message after making a POST request to the route *api/users*:

> [Nest] 85372   - 03/26/2020, 14:04:49   [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot read property 'password' of undefined +23790ms

Inside my users.schema.ts file a get the errror message:

> Unexpected aliasing of 'this' to local variable.eslint(@typescript-eslint/no-this-alias)

My users.schema.ts looks like this (commented the line with the error):

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
import * as bcrypt from 'bcryptjs'

export const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    updatedAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

UserSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    const user = this; // This is marked as an error in vs code
    if (!user.isModified('password')) return next();

    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
        if (err) return next(err);
        bcrypt.hash(this.user.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
            if (err) return next();
            this.user.password = hash;
            next();
        });
    });
});

UserSchema.methods.checkPassword = (attempt, callback) => {
    bcrypt.compare(attempt, this.user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
        if (err) return callback(err);
        callback(null, isMatch);
    })
}
```

I tried to implement the same schema with an arrow function, but then I get the following error message after making a POST request to *api/users*:

> [Nest] 85947   - 03/26/2020, 14:09:30   [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot read property 'isModified' of undefined +22567ms

```
UserSchema.pre('save', (next) => {
    if (!this.user.isModified('password')) return next();

    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
        if (err) return next(err);
        bcrypt.hash(this.user.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
            if (err) return next();
            this.user.password = hash;
            next();
        });
    });
});
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use arrow functions, because you loose the track of `this`. Read the official documentation of arrow functions, there are some very good examples about "what is this in an array function". [MDN Arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

There are two solutions:

**Remove the arrow-function callback for bcrypt**

```js
UserSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  if (!this.isModified('password')) return next();

  bcrypt.genSalt(10, function (err, salt) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    bcrypt.hash(this.user.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
      if (err) return next();
      this.user.password = hash;
      next();
    });
  });
});
```

**Disable eslint rule and always use the user variable**

```
UserSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  const user = this;
  if (!this.isModified('password')) return next();

  bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
    if (err) return next(err);
    bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
      if (err) return next();
      user.password = hash;
      next();
    });
  });
});
```